# Why my computer shuts down tryng ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, shutdown, freeze

I have a bootable usb with ubuntu 18.04 LTS, when I try to test this operating system my computer freezes and then shuts down about 2 minutes later. I don't know if this problem occurs because my computer has an nvidia GTX 1060 graphics card.

Comment: You didn't specify which 18.04 ISO you tried (server/desktop, 18.04, 18.04.2, 18.04.3 etc), nor if you verified the ISO after download (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then then validated the write to your install media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any media used, be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/etc)

Comment: @guiverc is a desktop ISO and everything was verified

Comment: You still didn't specify if it was 18.04 or 18.04.1 with GA stack, or 18.04.2 with 18.10's stack, 18.04.3 with 19.04's stack, 18.04.4 with 19.10's HWE stack etc... Did you verify both stages? (please specify as I asked which ISO you used in prior comment yet you missed it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem once trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell laptop which had a little onboard Nvidia gpu . Worked around it through the GRUB boot menu, pressing 'e' to edit the boot parameters, finding the line that starts with "linux", and adding "nomodeset" (without the quotes) at the end of that line.